# Where to find the items I steal in AC3?

Tags: assassins-creed-3

Where can I find the items I steal from other people in Assassin's Creed 3?

Items such as Milk, Catnip, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those items are meant for the crafting system.
As such you can only view them in your homestead, when choosing to craft/trade items.

[Image http://flashyreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/I-want-an-AC-RTS.png](http://flashyreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/I-want-an-AC-RTS.png)

Comment: Thanks, in which sequence do I get it? I am in Seq 3 now.

Comment: @czchlong If I remember correctly, sequence 3 still belongs to *Haytham Kennway*. In this case, you'll reach the homestead at sequence 4, and will get access to the craft & trade feature starting with sequence 5.